# typescript compila path.basename en path.default.basename

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Tengo el siguiente problema.

```
import path from "path";
const nombreArchivo = path.basename(rutaArchivo);
```

Este código me lo transpila a

```
const path_1 = require("path");
const nombreArchivo = path_1.default.basename(rutaArchivo);
```

Evidentemente está mal y me da undefined property basename.
Intenté desestructurar el import pero lo transpila a otra cosa que también está mal.

```
const nombreArchivo = (0, path_1.basename)(rutaArchivo);
```

Si alguien sabe como puedo arreglarlo. gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas, en la definición de tipos que publica DefinitivelyTyped, [path es un namespace](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/path.d.ts), por lo que lo correcto es importarlo como

```
import * as path from 'path'
```

Al tratarlo, como en tu código, como si fuera un default export, el comportamiento final se ve afectado principalmente por el flag [esModuleInterop](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) (lee su descripción, es muy relevante para este caso de borde) y por `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`.

No sabría decir a ciencia cierta cómo cambia el resultado con las 4 combinaciones de esos dos. También influye el valor que tengas configurado en  `target` así como el atributo "type" de tu package.json.

Comment: Muchas gracias. No podía encontrar este tema en mis búsquedas y ahora que tu me respondes lo encuentro en todos lados xD el que no sabe es como el que no ve.

Comment: Y ojos que no ven, nada temen